# Temporarily disable UI update of a QTableView

Tags: qt, qt4, qtableview, qt4.8, qstandarditemmodel

I have a `QStandardItemModel` that provides data for a `QTableView` and a thread that inserts data into the model.

Is it possible to temporarily stop the model from updating the table view, and enable it later?

Answer (score 8):

you can use `setUpdatesEnabled(bool)` in your view to dis and enable the updates; maybe `blockSignals(bool)` could also be interesting calling it on your model; it should prevent the view from recieving the models update signals

Comment: The function `setUpdatesEnabled()` will effectively disable all paint events, which might be a little crude, but I realize now that maybe that's what the question is all about, avoiding flickering while updating the model with the new data.